# Postgres removing jsonb object from nested jsonb array

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, jsonb

I have a deeply nested json array. The array contains a list of json objects, I want to remove any of the objects that are matched based on a field within the object.

```
{
  "name": "John smith",
  "items": {
    "unknown-key-1": {
      "file-array": [
        {
          "file-id": "file-1"
        },
        {
          "file-id": "file-2"
        },
        {
          "file-id": "file-3"
        }
      ]
    },
    "unknown-key-2": {
      "file-array": [
        {
          "file-id": "file-1"
        },
        {
          "file-id": "file-2"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

So for example, say I want to remove all objects where the `file-id` is "file-1". My UPDATE statement would remove all jsonb objects matching that `file-id`. After the UPDATE my jsonb column would look like this:

```
{
  "name": "John smith",
  "items": {
    "unknown-key-1": {
      "file-array": [
        {
          "file-id": "file-2"
        },
        {
          "file-id": "file-3"
        }
      ]
    },
    "unknown-key-2": {
      "file-array": [
        {
          "file-id": "file-2"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I can achieve this when the array is at the top level of the json, or, when the array is nested inside an object and the key is known. But in this case the keys are dynamically generated (i.e "unknown-key-1", "unknown-key-2")

I understand that under proper circumstances I would normalise the data as this is an anti-pattern, however I have no choice. Also I want to do this using an UPDATE statement instead of a Postgres function.

Comment: I think the problem starts with "I have a deeply nested JSON array". You shouldn't store such stuff in a database column if you want to manipulate it. I know that doesn't help you, but next time choose a different design.

Comment: totally agree but as I said on the question I don't have a choice.

Comment: I jumped ahead a bit without making sure: are only the `unknown-keys` dynamic? Can you rely on `items`, `file-array` and `file-id`, or do you also need to assume those keys might vary in some way?

Comment: @Zegarek I can rely on those keys being constant. only `unknown-keys-x` is dynamic

Comment: the actual file-id values are also unknown, these are just arbitrary file id values. The outer most WHERE clause on the query would have a file-id value, and its those files that I would want to delete, i.e.... UPDATE etc etc WHERE file-id = 'abc123'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modifying the `jsonb` isn't as tricky as applying that as an update:

```sql
select jdata #- array['items',item,'file-array',file_index-1]::text[]
from test
    ,jsonb_each(jdata->'items')a(item,contents)
    ,jsonb_array_elements(contents->'file-array')with ordinality b(file_obj,file_index)
where (file_obj->>'file-id')='file-1';
```

for each row it lists its `items`, and for each of those, it lists what's under `file-array`. This produces the item names and file indices that can be filtered in `where` and used to subtract the path using [`#-`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE). Indexes resulting from [`with ordinality`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLEFUNCTIONS) are 1-based, while `jsonb` arrays are 0-based, hence the `-1`.

The problem with using that directly as an update batch is that it results in single, separate, atomic changes based on each file to be removed from each value, and each row would apply only one of those small changes. In your example, only the file under `unknown-key-2` *or* `unknown-key-1` would get the `file-1` removed, not both. See the [notes under `update` doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html#id-1.9.3.183.8):

> When using `FROM` you should ensure that the join produces at most one output row for each row to be modified. In other words, a target row shouldn't join to more than one row from the other table(s). If it does, then **only one** of the join rows will be used to update the target row, but which one will be used is not readily predictable.

You'd have to either keep running the same update until you no longer see rows being affected, or you need to squash the updates so that each row gets only one cumulative change to apply: [demo at db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/RLvWPa5O)

```sql
with recursive required_changes as (
    select id,
      jdata,
      item,
      file_index-1 as file_index,
      row_number()over(partition by id) as update_round
    from test
        ,jsonb_each(jdata->'items')a(item,contents)
        ,jsonb_array_elements(contents->'file-array')
         with ordinality b(file_obj,file_index)
    where (file_obj->>'file-id')='file-1')
,iteratively_merged_changes as (
    select id,
         jdata#-array['items',item,'file-array',file_index]::text[] jdata,
         2 as next_round
    from required_changes where update_round=1
    union
    select a.id,
         a.jdata#-array['items',item,'file-array',file_index]::text[],
         a.next_round+1
    from iteratively_merged_changes a join required_changes b 
    on a.id=b.id 
    and b.update_round=a.next_round)
,final_batch as (
    select distinct on(id)id,jdata 
    from iteratively_merged_changes order by id,next_round desc)
update test t set jdata=f.jdata
from final_batch f where t.id=f.id
returning t.*;
```

The first CTE finds what path needs to be removed from which row, second one keeps applying those changes iteratively, one on top of another and the third one with [`distinct on`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT) just passes the final value from the latest round with all changes applied, to the outer `update`.

`WITH` needs to be [`RECURSIVE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-RECURSIVE) for the second one to be able to self-reference, but only that one does it. [More tests](https://dbfiddle.uk/CcTR6jQ3)

Answer (score 0):

@Zegarek's answer is useful when you know exactly what specific key names you need to look for in your entire JSON object, and also when you know the general structure and location of the target objects. However, in general cases, you will need to be able to handle any key names and any object structure and composition. The query below first finds the paths to every item in the JSON, and then uses those paths to search for the objects targeted for removal and then performs the removal in a recursive `cte`

```
with recursive cte(id, obj, arr, path) as (
   -- get all paths to every item in the object, regardless of key name and structure
   select t.id, case when jsonb_typeof(t.js) = 'object' then t.js else '{"null":null}'::jsonb end, 
      case when jsonb_typeof(t.js) = 'array' then t.js else '[null]'::jsonb end, ''
   from tbl t
   union all
   select c.id, case when jsonb_typeof(p_obj.value) = 'object' then p_obj.value 
      when jsonb_typeof(p_arr.value) = 'object' then p_arr.value else 
         (case when jsonb_typeof(p_obj.value) in ('array', 'object') or  
             jsonb_typeof(p_arr.value) in ('array', 'object') then '{"null":null}'::jsonb else '{}'::jsonb end) end,
      case when jsonb_typeof(p_obj.value) = 'array' then p_obj.value 
        when jsonb_typeof(p_arr.value) = 'array' then p_arr.value else 
         (case when jsonb_typeof(p_obj.value) in ('array', 'object') or  
             jsonb_typeof(p_arr.value) in ('array', 'object') then '[null]'::jsonb else '[]'::jsonb end) end,
      c.path || case when c.path != '' then ',' else '' end || case when p_arr.value#>>'{}' is not null then cast(p_arr.r as text) else p_obj.key end
   from cte c cross join jsonb_each(c.obj) p_obj cross join lateral (
      select row_number() over (order by 1) - 1 r, k.value 
      from jsonb_array_elements(c.arr) k) p_arr 
),
paths as (
   -- find the paths generated in the cte above that contain a key 'file-id' with a corresponding value of 'file-1' 
   select c.id, ('{'||c.path||'}')::text[] path from cte c join tbl t on t.id = c.id 
   where ((t.js#>('{'||c.path||'}')::text[]) -> 'file-id')#>>'{}' = 'file-1' 
),
load_update as (
   select row_number() over (partition by p.id) r, p.id, t.js, p.path from paths p join tbl t on p.id = t.id
),
perform_update as (
   -- make the updates in-place
   select u.r, u.id, u.js #- u.path js from load_update u where u.r = 1
   union all
   select u.r, u.id, p.js #- u.path js 
   from perform_update p join load_update u on u.r = p.r + 1 and p.id = u.id
)
update tbl set js = p.js from perform_update p 
where tbl.id = p.id and p.r = (select max(p1.r) from load_update p1 where p1.id = p.id)
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/U5-Fa3S8)

Comment: Nope, you only need to know the two [OP specified as constant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77695725/postgres-removing-jsonb-object-from-nested-jsonb-array/77699751#comment136979893_77695725). I'll be happy to read into it but from the first glance, I'm surprised you're still squashing the update - reconstructing the value should be possible without having to resort to that, just by fattening up what [@Laurenz already did](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77696873/5298879) with the conditions.

Comment: @Zegarek My point is that the other solutions so far require knowledge of not just `file-id` and `"file-1"` but also `items` and `file-array`, which the OP makes no mention of being known. As such, they cannot scale beyond the toy example.

Comment: Mine does, there's a fiddle with additional tests at the end. I get your idea now: you upgraded the query to target the value by the mere smell, by the sound it makes. I'm afraid you overdid that a bit, because it now seems to [obliterate innocent bystanders](https://dbfiddle.uk/mmEs5MbH), pretty aggresively.

Comment: "unknown-key-x" is the only key which isn't known, the actual "file-id" values (I.e file-1, file-2, file-3) are also unknown, but these are values and not keys, so they are just arbitrary file-id values. My UDPATE query would take a file-id in the where clause and that would be the criteria for which objects to delete